# Using the correct version of vim

Tags: vim, homebrew, macvim

I installed vim with:

`brew install vim --override-system-vi`

I also installed macvim using:

`brew install macvim`

However, terminal vim uses 7.4.52 and macvim uses 7.4.22. Any way around this?

I've uninstalled and reinstalled many times, but I must be doing it wrong...

`which vim` returns `/usr/local/bin/vim`

`which mvim` returns `/usr/local/bin/mvim`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thnx!

Comment: Macvim comes with its own vim binary. So its not surprising that terminal vim and MacVim have different versions.

Comment: It's not surprising at all. There's a way you can use a different version. I didn't it before, but I can't for the life of me remember how. I just remember using homebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to install macvim: it runs both as a GUI and in the terminal.

I don't know where the confusion comes from but neither gvim nor macvim are frontends for a separate vim. They are vim.

Comment: I see... I'm rather new to vim, so I wasn't sure exactly how that worked. Okay, how do I update the vim version that macvim is? Perhaps homebrew doesn't have the latest version up or maybe macvim hasn't caught up to the latest updated version?

Comment: @DavidBecerra MacVim is a separate vim branch (upstream vim + some mac-specific stuff). Thus there is some lag between the time when some patch is accepted in Vim upstream and the time when it is merged into macvim. As you may see [here](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/commits/master) latest macvim version is 7.4.052 which was merged from upstream a month ago. Latest vim version is 7.4.079. I do not know what is the lag between homebrew update (if there is such a thing: I am not using Mac) and macvim upstream change.

Comment: Macvim's latest snapshot is 7.4.52. It almost always lags behind the official source which is used by the vim formula. Since you want a GUI you should stick with Macvim, thoug. However lagging it is.

Comment: Remember to tick an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can rename your system vim, then vim will be the mac vim

Answer (score 0):

You've installed two different pieces of software..but you only want to use one? If so, then just alias your macvim in your shell; for example:

alias vim="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"